# Getting "connect ECONNREFUSED" error when I "npm run seed" in feathers api with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, api, npm, feathersjs

I'm learning react and feathers. For my recipes app that I've made in react I use feathers api and mongodb. I have some seeds as examples in `/src/seeds.js` and just began to set up everything in feathers but when I want to run my seeds(`npm run seed`) and check if it works on feathers `localhost:3030/recipes` I got this error:

```
Error creating user! { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3030
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3030,
  response: undefined }
```

I don't know the error is because of connection or creating user!
I checked my mondo db, it runs.

this is package.json, just in case:

```
{
  "name": "recipes-api(par)",
  "description": "api for recipes app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "",
  "main": "src/",
  "keywords": [
    "feathers"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {},
  "author": {},
  "contributors": [],
  "bugs": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run jshint && npm run mocha",
    "jshint": "jshint src/. test/. --config",
    "start": "node src/",
    "mocha": "mocha test/ --recursive",
    "seed": "node src/seeds.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "feathers": "^2.1.1",
    "feathers-authentication": "^0.7.12",
    "feathers-client": "^2.2.0",
    "feathers-configuration": "^0.3.3",
    "feathers-errors": "^2.6.3",
    "feathers-hooks": "^1.8.1",
    "feathers-mongoose": "^3.6.2",
    "feathers-rest": "^1.7.2",
    "feathers-socketio": "^1.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.6",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.2",
    "superagent": "^3.5.2",
    "winston": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.9.4",
    "mocha": "^3.3.0",
    "request": "^2.81.0"
  }
}
```

Before adding seeds I should have seen  `{"total":0,"limit":5,"skip":0,"data":[]}` in `http://localhost:3030/recipes` that I'm still having it but after running seeds I should see the list of my recipes.

Anythings else that I need to copy here from my code? any idea?

Comment: Check your database if it contains the seeded data. If not then, might be because `127.0.0.1:3030` is not available. Possibly it is running on a different port. Check your `/config/default.json` for this.

By default, prior to seeding and given that your service is available doing something like `http://localhost:3030/<yourservice>` should show `{"total":0,"limit":10,"skip":0,"data":[]}`

Comment: @Jalil this is my `default.json` : `{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 3030,
  "mongodb": "mongodb://localhost:27017/recipesApi",
  "public": "../public/",
  "auth": {
    "token": {
      "secret": "4qrMWfG9QCRX5eDMhCLlDpe4XFIRyqx1u+Enbo2fE/iY7YZ9mvjR28ZZpQx1/wkn3ljHSAIVlNXjnUXIkWZHLw=="
    },
    "local": {}
  }
}`

Comment: My suggestion to you now is update feathers version since you are still using the old 0.7.x. There is also `feathers-cli` that will show you how should they be structure and it will also use the latest version of feathers.

Comment: I updated my feathers and generate my api app again. In new one it doesn't even generate models for me. I made my models myself and now It doesn't work at all. It's getting more complicated with new versions.I think I'm gonna read its documentation. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it is really confusing right now because you started when feathers is having a major updates. Download the latest [feathers-cli](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-cli). See the documentation and see the commands. It is good in setting up your firs projects and as a reference.